# jquery file upload - having more than one upload_dir

Tags: jquery, file-upload, directory, laravel

I am using the Jquery file upload plugin, in particular this one:
http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/jUpload

I wish to be able to set the upload_dir differently for different web pages.
Is this possible? If so, how can I set upload_dir based on different web page requirements?

It is currently set in settings.php though these values are shared across the plugin (which am sure is the purpose).

```
upload_dir = '/users/folder1/files.txt'; //web page 1
upload_dir = '/users/folder2/files.txt'; //web page 2
```

any ideas on making the above possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue as follows:

1) created a separate main.js file for each web page, e.g. main.js, main.js
2) created a separate settings file (though this is not strictly required)
3) at runtime in my route after getting values from the settings file, I add the page specific 'upload_dir' to the $options array, just before instantiating the UploadHandler.

and that's it :)